# An absent Panim Chadashos at Sheva Brachos

Tags: halacha, blessing, mistakes, sheva-brachos

If you make a Sheva Brachos meal for a new Chosson and Kallah and your Panim Chadashos (new person) does not show up, can you still say the Sheva Brachos?

Comment: Why 'can...still' instead of 'do'? Either way you have made the Chosson and Kallah happy; isn't that the goal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Gemara [Ketubot (8a)](http://www.sefaria.org/Ketubot.8a.10?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) states that after the first day, Rav Ashei would only recite the sheva berakhot if there was someone new. The implication is that it is a complete requirement, and no exception is made if you wanted to have someone new who never came. One would only recite "Asher bara" as stated there in Ketubot.

This is referenced in numerous sources with no exception stated for a case where for whatever reason one does not have panim chadashot. These sources include Seder Rav Amram Gaon (Seder Eirussin V'nissuin), Rambam's [Hilkhot Berakhot (2:10)](http://mechon-mamre.org/i/2502.htm#10), Tur ([EH 62](http://www.sefaria.org/Tur,_Even_HaEzer.62?lang=bi)), and the Shulhan Arukh ([EH 62:7](http://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Even_HaEzer.62.7?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)).

Answer (score 7):

Especially if it's Shabbos or Yom Tov, some have the minhag to say it anyway (Shulchan Aruch Even Ha'ezer 62:8). The "Asher Barah" blessing may be said even if there are no Panim Chadashos (62:7).

Comment: What about during the week?

Answer (score 0):

Not an authoritative answer at all, but: I have known cases where a *sheva b'rachos* host would call around to various people to find a last-minute "*panim chadashos*". As always, [CYLOR](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/CYLOR).

Comment: This just implies that _lechatchila_ (or at least in those cases) we want PC to be there, not what would happen if they didn't show.